# How to make partial refund of stripe payment in laravel

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I have integrate stripe as payment gateway in my application develop in laravel. I am also able to make full refund using below code.

```
$stripe = Stripe::make('sk_test_******');
    $charge_id = Session::get('charge_id');
    $amount = Session::get('payment_amount');
    $refund = $stripe->refunds()->create(
         $charge_id
    );
```

Now i want to allow admin to make partial refund to customer from backend, I have try below code for that as per stripe documents.

```
$stripe = Stripe::make('sk_test_**********');
$charge_id = Session::get('charge_id');
$amount = Session::get('payment_amount');       
$refund = $stripe->refunds()->create([
    'charge' => $charge_id,
    'amount' => '5',
    'reason' => 'refund'
]);
```

But i got error like **Array to string conversion**. Can anyone help me to solve this error or tell me what is wrong in this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From stripe  [documentation](https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe/2.0), it is clearly mentioned that you have to set APIKEY it the following way

```
$stripe = new Stripe();
$stripe = Stripe::make('YOUR API KEY');

$charge_id = Session::get('charge_id');
$amount = Session::get('payment_amount');       
$refund = $stripe->refunds()->create( $charge_id,$amount, ['reason' => 'refund'
]);
```

**Caution**: To refund part of a charge, provide an amount parameter, as an integer in cents or the charge currency’s smallest currency unit of the specific currency you are using.

Comment: I have use **Cartalyst\Stripe\Stripe** for integrate stripe with my laravel application. and i have implement its syntax

Comment: refund create function looks ok, can you point out on which line you are getting this error ?

Comment: $stripe->refunds()->create($chargeId = 15515415, $amount = 5, $meta); here meta should be the extra parameters you want to post to the stripe

Comment: I have this code and got error **syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ')'**.

Comment: I just added updated code in my solution please have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187115/discussion-between-muhammad-sipra-and-adarsh-bhatt).

Answer (score 1):

Because you are passing the wrong parameters. Change:

```
$refund = $stripe->refunds()->create([
    'charge' => $charge_id,
    'amount' => '5',
    'reason' => 'refund'
]);
```

to:

```
$refund = $stripe->refunds()->create($charge_id, 5, ['reason' => 'refund']);
```